# Include multiple graphics with R-markdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have an R vector of filepaths for pdf figures I would like to put into my knitr document and knit to html. I see that I can get a single pdf to be included with

```
knitr::include_graphics(filepaths[1])
```

My filepaths vector is long and changes size between document compilations. Is there a method of including them all in one go. I had imagined this would work.

```
for(i in filepaths){knitr::include_graphics(i)}
```

Had also tried:

```
for(i in filepaths){ print("![](", filepaths[i], ")" ) }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`knitr::include_graphics()` is vectorized, so the answer is simply:

```
knitr::include_graphics(filepaths)
```

Your first solution does not work because `knitr::include_graphics()` needs to be [the top-level expression](https://yihui.name/en/2017/06/top-level-r-expressions/). Your second solution does not work because you should use `cat()` instead of `print()`, and the chunk option `results='asis'`.

[There are several advantages](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/figures.html) of using `include_graphics()` over `cat()` + `results='asis'`.

Comment: So is there a way to force knitr::include_graphics() to be in a for loop and work? I am trying to print the file name between png files so the reader knows which file the graph is coming from.  I tried to wrap it in withVisibile and it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes there is :) see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50824249/11524079) answer, which follows from Yihui's blog post. Just wrap it in a `print` call.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `cat` instead of `include_graphics`. For example:

```
for(i in 1:length(filepaths) {
    cat("![](", filepaths[i], ")")
}
```

This is general Markdown syntax: `![NAME](PATH)`.
With this solution you will need to use `results = "asis"` in chunk header.