# How to display plot images in Rmarkdown through a for loop?

Tags: r, svg, r-markdown

I am handling a list of `svg` to print to a html document. I am using the `magick` package thought I am open to using other packages/solutions. The below code is my attempt to render my html document. However, instead of rendering the `svg` to the html file, it simply prints the metadeta into the document. Is there a way to overcome this behavior?

````
---
title: "My Test Report"
author: "Nicholas Hayden"
date: "6/12/2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, set-options, include=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(rsvg)
library(magick)

paths <- c(
"~/path/to/my1.svg",
"~/path/to/my2.svg")

for (i in 1:length(paths)) {
  print(image_read_svg(paths[i]))
}
```
````

EDIT:

### Some examples that elucidate the problem.

The `Rmd` command:

`![]("~/path/to/my1.svg")` fails and produces...

```
File "/Users/nicholashayden/Desktop/path/to/my1.svg" not found in resource path
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99
```

As @mikeck pointed out. This may be a pathing issue. However, trying without the `~` produces the same error.

---

The html plain text of `<img src="/Users/nicholashayden/path/to/my1.svg">` places the image in the html document while the `~` version fails with the same error as the previous.

---

The `knitr::include_graphics()` method produces whitespace with either the absolute path or the path with the `~`

---

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use `include_graphics`:

````
```{r}
for (i in 1:length(paths)) {
  print(knitr::include_graphics(paths[i]))
}
```
````

Comment: The `knitr::include_graphics(paths[i])` fails to display the vector graphic in the html document. It produces a white space.

Comment: @Nicholas, when you look at the source of your html document, do the image paths actually make sense? You may need to provide absolute paths if you are not saving your knitr output to the current directory, or fix the relative paths your are specifying in `paths`.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to do that. I go into vim and hit the `?` and look for my filepath and it does not exist. In other ways to troubleshoot - Simply writing, `image_read_svg(paths[i])` outside of the for loop prints the image to the html file. So, I am not quite sure it is a pathing problem unless maybe the `~` is not considered an absolute path.

Comment: This does not seem to work when output is a pdf document

Comment: The reason the "print" statement is required has been explained by yihui [here](https://yihui.org/en/2017/06/top-level-r-expressions/).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution to this problem and its a bit of a pseudo-solution that gets the task completed but without explaining the underlying mechanism that generated the problem.

According to the `knitr::include_graphics()` documentation, the `path` argument is a `A character vector of image paths` - emphasis on **vector**. We can display the `.svg` files without `magick` and simply use, in references in the example, the below code.

---

```
# From example
paths <- c(
"/Users/nicholashayden/path/to/my1.svg",
"/Users/nicholashayden/path/to/my2.svg")

# Solution
knitr::include_graphics(paths)
```

---

This way we can avoid the use of the `for` loop that for some reason caused this problem. Though, this will not work with `~` in the path string. My issue was overlooking **and** assuming arguments in the `knitr::include_graphics()` function. Hopes this helps anyone in the future.

Comment: I'm guessing the `~` is why your original solution didn't work. In my answer, I initially forgot to `print` the call to `include_graphics`, so the for loop didn't actually produce the image paths.