# Image not rendering within for loop in rmarkdown

Tags: r, image, pdf, r-markdown

I'm trying to loop through a series of sites and produce a sheet that has text, an image, and a table for each site.  I'm using Rmarkdown with PDF output, and am able to get all of the pieces working when I manually select a site and run the code, but can't get the image to show up in the output document when I try to use a for loop.

Following the advice on [How to display plot images in Rmarkdown through a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824040/how-to-display-plot-images-in-rmarkdown-through-a-for-loop) I've tried adding `print()` to my call to `knitr::include_graphics()`, and this shows the path to my image followed by  [1] “knit_image_paths” “knit_asis”
My path shows up correctly in my output document, and I am using complete absolute paths.

My code:

```
library(tidyverse) ## for %>%
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)  

dt = mtcars[1:5,]
car_names = rownames(dt)
dt$Photo = c("a.jpg", "b.jpg", NA, NA, "c.jpg")
photos_folder = "C:/examples"
photos = list.files(photos_folder, pattern = ".jpg")

for(car in car_names){
     writeLines(car)
     writeLines("\nSome text goes here \n")
     image  = ifelse(
            is.na(dt$Photo), "No Photo",
            photos[str_detect(photos, dt$Photo)]
      )

      if(is.na(row$Photo)) writeLines(image)
         
      if(!is.na(row$Photo)) include_graphics(file.path(photos_folder, image)) %>% 
           print()

  dt %>% 
       select(mpg, qsec, carb) %>%
       kbl() %>%
       print()
     
}
```

If I set `car = car_names[1]`, comment out the for loop, and take out the call to `print()` for the image everything shows up correctly. With the for loop, nothing shows up where the image should be unless I add the call to `print()` back in, but in this case I get the path and the options.

Comment: May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650166/r-why-kable-doesnt-print-inside-a-for-loop) helps

Comment: I was able to get images to show up by manually constructing the pandoc call:

```
      if(!is.na(row$Photo)) {
            writeLines(paste0("![](",file.path(photos_folder, image),")"))
      }
```
Unfortunately, this approach gives up some of the control that `include_graphics()` provides. I would still like a way to use `include_graphics()`